# Measure performance of a Web Server

Tags: performance, webserver

Which tools can be used to measure performance of a webserver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test a webserver, you can use [Apache Jmeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/).

Comment: @Aditya: Your question said "web server"

Comment: Yes , I am curious about ngnix.

Comment: Jmeter is an application you run and you create some TestSuites that launch connections to any webserver. For example, to test an HTTP Server load performance, you can test 1000 users trying to get a HTML page repeteadly at the same time for 10 minutes.

Comment: The tester is independent from the webserver since you can ask HTTP requests to any webserver, would it be Apache, Tomcat or Ngnix :)

Answer (score 1):

To see where is the bottleneck you have to flood your server application.

ApacheBench (ab) can do this. Here is a tool to get the server HTTP response code (ab) just says there is an HTTP error, and to automate test runs:

dsec.com/source/ab.c.txt

This program also gives useful tips about how to configure Linux and Windows (TCP/IP system options) to get the best possible performances.

Comment: Thanks fred , that's a great suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It always depends on the setup.

Depending on the application there can be different bottlenecks.

Sometimes its the CPU, sometimtes the database connections, sometimes the sockets, sometimes the hard disc etc...

Most common practice is to use siege (simple command line tool) and increase the concurrent connections and see how many transactions per second go through.

It will increase per connection until an optimum is reached, then it will slowly decrase.

You can produce a set of urls that are randomly accessed, maby biased and/or send random data, request random ids etc to simulate more "real" clients.

Completely depends on your application whether this is relevant.